# Counting the total number of reviews for a given product

Tags: php, mysql, zen-cart

I'm trying to pull the total number of reviews for a product page template and for some reason I keep getting a result of one no matter what even though there's at least 2.

Can anyone help?

I have the following bits of code written.

```
$reviews_query_raw = "SELECT r.reviews_id, rd.reviews_text as reviews_text, r.reviews_rating, r.date_added, r.customers_name
                    FROM " . TABLE_REVIEWS . " r, " . TABLE_REVIEWS_DESCRIPTION . " rd
                    WHERE r.products_id = :productsID
                    AND r.reviews_id = rd.reviews_id
                    AND rd.languages_id = :languagesID " . $review_status . "
                    ORDER BY r.reviews_id desc";

$reviews_query_raw = $db->bindVars($reviews_query_raw, ':productsID', $_GET['products_id'], 'integer');
$reviews_query_raw = $db->bindVars($reviews_query_raw, ':languagesID', $_SESSION['languages_id'], 'integer');
$reviews_split = new splitPageResults($reviews_query_raw, MAX_DISPLAY_NEW_REVIEWS);
$reviews = $db->Execute($reviews_split->sql_query);
```

And then later in the page:

```
<?php echo $reviews->RecordCount(); ?>
```

And it's returning one. Even though I can run the same query in phpMyAdmin and get actual results.

Comment: Where are you seeing a result of 1? I see no `COUNT(*)` aggregate in your query.

Comment: I'm using the ZenCart function: $reviews->RecordCount() to display the results. Should I do something else?

Comment: I'm guessing the "1" is a truthy result - like a return value of true on a resource pointer, converted to a string on output - but, in this case, it's for whatever `$db->Execute()` returns. It needs an iterator of some sort I'd guess - or a `count()` if it's an array.

Comment: @CD001: But I'm not sure if I should be getting that result after using the "RecordCount" procedure by ZenCart when it's the same one used on other pages as well.

Answer (score 1):

You've set MAX_DISPLAY_NEW_REVIEWS to 1. splitPageResults class paginates Your original query, so transformed query has something like 'LIMIT 0, 1' at the end. To get total number of reviews use:

```
<?php echo $reviews_split->number_of_rows;?>
```

to know how many pages are required to display all reviews using current setting of MAX_DISPLAY_NEW_REVIEWS use:

```
<?php echo $reviews_split->number_of_pages;?>
```

You can change MAX_DISPLAY_NEW_REVIEWS in admin area in Configuration->Maximum/Minimum values